# mysql query with WHERE IF and FIND_IN_SET() function

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using the following query:

```
 "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE IF(FIND_IN_SET(column1,'$searchString') > 0,1,0) 
+ IF(FIND_IN_SET(column2, '$searchString') > 0, 1, 0) 
+ IF(FIND_IN_SET(column3, '$searchString') > 0, 1, 0)+ 
IF(FIND_IN_SET(column4, '$searchString') > 0, 1, 0) > 0";
```

So (in case) after 4 successful matches, does the query becomes the following??:

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1+1+1+1 > 0";
```

Please ensure me whether my assumption is right. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you can make this shorter

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE 
(
    FIND_IN_SET(column1, '$searchString') > 0 +
    FIND_IN_SET(column2, '$searchString') > 0 + 
    FIND_IN_SET(column3, '$searchString') > 0 + 
    FIND_IN_SET(column4, '$searchString') > 0
) > 0
```

Comment: thanks, i guess this query will give better performance when the database becomes big?

Comment: You can run it with `explain select ...` to see for yourself. But my guess it that there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would do this type of comparison with `or` unless you want really want to count the matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(column1, '$searchString') > 0 OR
       FIND_IN_SET(column2, '$searchString') > 0 OR 
       FIND_IN_SET(column3, '$searchString') > 0 OR
       FIND_IN_SET(column4, '$searchString') > 0
      );
```

Comment: Is it possible like if condition true then FIND_IN_SET will be execute?